# Why the length is lower semi-continuous?

Tags: metric-spaces, metric-geometry, semicontinuous-functions

I'm reading the book [*A Course in Metric Geometry*](https://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/akp-papers/bbi.pdf) by Dmitri Burago, Yuri Burago Sergei Ivanov and I don't understand the proof of Proposition 2.5.17 (Page 48).

More precisely, I don't know why the length is lower semi-continuous. I know the length induced by metric is semi-continuous, but I don't know why it is true for general length.

> **Proposition 2.5.17.** *If shortest path $\gamma_i $ in a length space $ (X,d) $ converge to a path $ \gamma $ as $ i\rightarrow\infty $, then $ \gamma $ is also a shortest path.*
>
> **Proof.** Since the endpoints of $ \gamma_i $ converge to endpoints of $ \gamma $ and the length of each $ \gamma_i $ is equal to the distance between its points, we conclude that $ L(\gamma_i) \rightarrow d(x,y) $, where $ x, y $ are the endpoints of $ \gamma $. By the lower semi-continuity of length $$ L(\gamma) \leq \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} L(\gamma_i) = d(x,y). $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would likely help people a *lot* that could answer your question if you include the proof in question in your post; I doubt everyone has that text on-hand, or is willing to go out and find it.

Comment: For those of us who do not have a copy of "A Course in Metric Geometry" sitting beside us, would you mind including the relevant proposition, proof, and context in your question?

Comment: The length in question is indeed the length induced by the metric $d$

Comment: @DanteGrevino Could you explain with more detail? I think $ d $ is obtained from a length structure $ (A,L) $ and the length in the proof is $ L, $ right? I did not see why $ L $ is induced by $ d. $

Comment: By default $L$ is the length induced by $d$. Moreover, this is necessarily the case because they use the lower semi-continuity of the length

Answer (score 2):

Given a metric space $(X,d)$ we can measure the length $L(c)$ of a path $c:[a,b]\to X$ by the formula

$$L(c)=\sup_{a=t_0<\ldots<t_k=b}\sum_{i=1}^kd(c(t_{i-1}),c(t_i))$$

where the supremum is taken over all possible (finite) partitions of the interval $[a,b]$.

This length satisfies the lower semi-continuity property: for every sequence $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of paths $c_n:[a,b]\to X$ which converges pointwise to a path $c:[a,b]\to X$, we have that $L(c)\leq\liminf L(c_n)$.

On the other hand, if $d$ is an intrinsic metric induced by a length structure $(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{L})$, then $L=\mathcal{L}$ (on the set $\mathcal{C}$ of admissible paths) if and only if $\mathcal{L}$ is lower semi-continuous (on $\mathcal{C}$).

Thus, in your quote, the authors call $L$ to the length induced by $d$.